# How to change RPM's destination when using rpmbuild

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building an RPM with rpmbuild from a spec file in a directory `foo` but whenever I run rpmbuild it creates the rpm in my home directory at `~/rpmbuild/RPMS`.

How can I change the destination of the RPM and get the whole rpmbuild directory to be in `foo`? I tried setting `Buildroot` to `foo` but that just changed where the build built temporary files, not the final rpm. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information in the (sometimes really dated) Maximum RPM manual is still up-to-date.  You need to set the `_topdir` value to move the entire directory tree:

- [Having RPM Use a Different Build Area](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-anywhere-different-build-area.html)

Apart from changing `~/.rpmmacros`, you can also use `-D _topdir /path/to/alternate/location` to switch the location of the directory tree.

If you want to move specific subdirectories, see [`rpmrc` File Entries](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpmrc-file-rpmrc-file-entries.html) and search for `topdir` references for the other RPM macro names.  Note that for some reason, the leading underscore `_` is missing from all those variables names.

Comment: I prefer `--define "_topdir /x/x/x"` so the next person editing the calling script doens't have to guess `-D`. And *there is no = anywhere* in there, as in this answer's example.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to the above answer that works, to set the output directory in the spec file itself `%define _rpmdir /path/to/outputdir` worked for me.